# Data argument not used by string? (two variables in one)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

i have been looking for solutions for this but they can't seem to be able to fix this error.

my Xcode prompts this error

```
"data argument not used by string"
```

i am allowing the user to input the contact the user would like to search so that i can prompt back the searched details

how do i fix this?
where is the problem?

thanks ahead

here's the code:

```
initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected contact: %@",
    (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(_person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty),
    (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(_person, &kABPersonLastNameProperty)]
    delegate:self 
    otherButtonTitles:@"Send Email",nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing two strings, but your format only has one `%@` in it.  One of the strings is unused, and this probably isn't what you wanted, so you get a warning.

Try using

```
@"Selected contact: %@%@"
```